# Sending an Image via MQTT

Tags: image, base64, mqtt, publisher, subscriber

I am trying to send an image using MQTT. I have been able to send and receive other kinds of data using mqtt but for the image I am not receving anything.

I am using base64 to convert image into bytes and then publish it to a broker. Then on the subcriber side I am using base64 to convert it into image again and save the image in the working directory.

This is my publisher

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt 
import time
import base64

mqttBroker ="test.mosquitto.org" 

client = mqtt.Client("Temperature_Inside")
client.connect(mqttBroker) 


while True:
    with open("car.jpg","rb") as image:
            img = image.read()
        
    message =img
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(message)
    base64_message =base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
    client.publish("TEMPERATURE", base64_message)
    print("Just published to topic TEMPERATURE")
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is my subscriber

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import base64

mqttBroker ="test.mosquitto.org"
client = mqtt.Client("Smartphone")
client.connect(mqttBroker) 
client.loop_start()
client.subscribe("TEMPERATURE")


def on_message(client, userdata, message): 
    msg = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    img = msg.encode('ascii')
    final_msg = base64.b64decode(img)
    open('received_image.jpg','wb').write(final_msg)


client.on_message=on_message 

time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: If the image is bigger than the MTU of the network you are running on you will need to start the client loop for the publisher as well

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding at all? MQTT is perfectly able to transmit binary data, and base64 encoding it needlessly makes it 30% bigger.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to base64 encode/decode images with MQTT as it is perfectly able to transmit binary data such as images.

So, you can publish like this:

```
with open("car.jpg","rb") as image:
    img = image.read()
client.publish("images", image)
```

and subscribe like this:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message): 
    open('received_image.jpg','wb').write(message.payload)
```